# pe:ckEditor doesn't work anymore after adding CombinedResourceHandler

Tags: jsf, ckeditor, omnifaces, primefaces-extensions, combinedresourcehandler

I added [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) to use the [`CombinedResourceHandler`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CombinedResourceHandler).
But now the [PrimeFaces Extensions](http://primefaces-extensions.github.io/) [`<pe:ckEditor>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/ckEditor.jsf) doesn´t work anymore.

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known issue caused by the way how PrimeFaces Extensions loads and manages its JS resources. This was already ever reported as an issue on old Google Code host and is mentioned in the current [OmniFaces known issues wiki](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/wiki/Known-Issues-(general)#primefaces-extensions--071-and-probably-future-versions) as follows:

> ### PrimeFaces Extensions <=0.7.1-4.0.0 (and probably future versions)
>
> PrimeFaces Extensions JS resource `primefaces-extensions.js` is incompatible with `CombinedResourceHandler`. During load, it attempts to figure the version from its own `<script>` element in order to dynamically load additional CSS/JS resources. This is however absent and the attempt fails with a JS error which in turn causes the dynamic loading of additional CSS/JS resources for e.g. CKEditor to fail.
>
> Your best bet is to exclude `primefaces-extensions.js` from combining by adding the following entry to `web.xml` telling the `CombinedResourceHandler` to not combine the PrimeFaces Extensions main script file:
>
> ```
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>org.omnifaces.COMBINED_RESOURCE_HANDLER_EXCLUDED_RESOURCES</param-name> 
>     <param-value>primefaces-extensions:primefaces-extensions.js</param-value> 
> </context-param>
> ```
>
> If you're using OmniFaces 2.2 or newer, then you can use a wildcard `*` as name:
>
> ```
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>org.omnifaces.COMBINED_RESOURCE_HANDLER_EXCLUDED_RESOURCES</param-name> 
>     <param-value>primefaces-extensions:*</param-value> 
> </context-param>
> ```
>
> If you're using PrimeFaces Extensions *before* version 3.0.0, then you also need to make sure that the PrimeFaces Extensions own resource handler is explicitly declared *after* `CombinedResourceHandler` in `faces-config.xml`:
>
> ```
> <application>
>     <resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CombinedResourceHandler</resource-handler>
>     <resource-handler>org.primefaces.extensions.application.PrimeFacesExtensionsResourceHandler</resource-handler>
> </application>
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there any plan for solving this issue? Any date?

Comment: It's not possible from OmniFaces side on. In essence, PrimeFaces Extensions shouldn't be trying to check its version based on `<script src>`, but use an alternate way. E.g. hardcoded (build-generated) in its main script file, or dynamically rendered in `<h:head>`.

Comment: could you post a example? Thank you very much. I want to us Omnifaces Resource Handler, but I should use Primefaces Extensions, also...

Comment: That would require modifying their sources. You'd better just exclude them from combining. I updated the answer with detail as to how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in PrimeFaces Extensions 6.2.8 or higher.

https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/601