# org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CombinedResourceHandler causes a JavaScript error to be issued, when a pe:ckEditor is used

Tags: jsf, omnifaces, primefaces-extensions, combinedresourcehandler

Using `org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CombinedResourceHandler` with,

- OmniFaces 2.2 final
- PrimeFaces 5.3 final
- PrimeFaces Extensions 4.0.0

There is a [`<pe:ckEditor>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/ckEditor/basicUsage.jsf) being used at one place in an application.

Simply trying to load the editor like the following.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <pe:ckEditor value="Contents" label="Label" height="200" width="1000"/>
</h:form>
```

leaves the following JavaScript error on the console.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

The test case contains nothing other than the basic XHTML structure and a `<pe:ckEditor>` tag.

The error disappears, when

```
<resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CombinedResourceHandler</resource-handler>
```

is removed from `faces-config.xml`.

The error is arriving from `primefaces-extensions.source.js`. Something wonky is likely to be happening in assembling / combining the JavaScript code into a single JavaScript file, when a `<pe:ckEditor>` is used.

It is also reproducible in OmniFaces 2.1 final

Comment: Is this still applicable? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003338/peckeditor-doesnt-work-anymore-after-adding-combinedresourcehandler

Comment: Done as directed.  `<pe:ckEditor>` related resources were not loaded. 404 at `javax.faces.resource/ckeditor/skins/moono/&v=null&v=null&v=null`, `javax.faces.resource/ckeditor/styles.js&v=null&v=null&v=null`.

Comment: Perhaps things changed in PE 4. Let me check.

Comment: They improved their resource handler. Explicitly registering it after the combined resource handler is unnecessary and only causes trouble you were seeing. Removing it from explicit registration worked for me. Only the context param for OmniFaces is sufficient. Does it now work for you too?

Comment: Dupe answer has been improved. Thanks! :) For the record, those were the fixes PE guys did making explicitly ordered registration unnecessary: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/commit/28a07ba and https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/commit/64dc30d

Comment: This question does not deserve an upvote, since it is a duplicate :)

Comment: All contributions to improving OmniFaces deserve an upvote.

Comment: Excluding `primefaces-extensions.js` from being included in a combined js file has a consequence which I could only see in the real application. I am also using other components from PrimeFaces Extensions like `<pe:blockUI>` which issue errors like `Uncaught ReferenceError: PrimeFacesExt is not defined` `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined` `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined`. It might be because `primefaces-extensions.js` is loaded after the combined js. Hence,  no reference from `primefaces-extensions.js` is available to the combined js.

Comment: Try to exclude `primefaces-extensions:*` instead.

Comment: I see something unusual. This `<param-value>primefaces-extensions:*</param-value>` excludes no JavaScript / CSS files.

Comment: Wildcard cupport for CRH was only added in OmniFaces 2.2.

Comment: I am using OmniFaces 2.2.

Comment: Hm, I tested it right before posting the comment and it worked for me.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. I am currently busy migrating the application from GlassFish to WildFly. Since the IDE behaves weirdly with WildFly in deploying applications, I had been testing this on GlassFish for the sake of convenience to deploy the application where I forgot to upgrade OmniFaces 2.1 to 2.2. Upgrading the library solved the problem entirely. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Those things happen :)